# iOS xcode poll method at regular intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class

I have written a class that handles communication over a network and I want a method in the ViewController class to watch certain variables in the communication class and update label text when data from the network is received. I tried calling a method at the end of the ViewDidLoad method after making the calls to establish the network communication but that attempt stopped the view from displaying, and monitoring the network I never saw a connection established.

What is the best way for a method in a ViewController class to watch for updates to public member variables in my communicator class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options

- **Key Value Observing**: You register your View Controller as an observer for a particular property in the other class. *Notes:* Easy to implement, but your connection class must modify a property that is KVO compliant.
- **Delegation**: you can create a protocol, and make your View Controller class be the delegate for the connection class. *Notes*: A little messy to implement, because you need to create the protocol, make you VC implement the protocol, and create a delegate object in the connection class
- **Notifications**: You can register the View Controller to receive a custom notification sent by the connection class. *Notes*: Easy to implement, and you can register many listeners without problems.
- **Callback Block**: You can pass a block from the View Controller to the connection class, and ask it to execute the block. *Notes*: Very simple and elegant, but blocks can be tricky.

Comment: Excellent answer - note that repeatedly polling is _not_ one of the recommended methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make your view controller to be  a delegate for communicator instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to advertise changes to other objects in your application